# Homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I have to compute the groups

$H_q(S^{3},S^1)$

(Singular Homology)
I am new in the subject, i have compute some basics groups, but i dont know how to start with this one, if someone could help me, give me some idea or something, thanks

Comment: Do you know the definition of a homology group? Also, I'm not sure I really understand what you mean by $H_q(S^3,S^1)$, is this the relative homology?

Comment: yes, is the relative homology

Comment: I already solve it using the theorem that Daniel mencione, but i was thinking if there is a way of compute the groups, i mean "by hand" instead on using those results

Comment: @Dimitri: Relative homology groups are designed to be computed through long exact sequences. You also have for CW-complexes $H_*(X,Y) = \tilde{H}_*(X/Y)$ (this is relative homology), but it's not always easier to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the theorems you need to remember:

If $A\stackrel{i}{\to} X$ is an inclusion of a subspace, then there is a long exact sequence in homology given by $$\cdots\to H_n(A)\stackrel{i_*}{\to} H_n(X)\to H_n(X,A)\to H_{n-1}(A)\to\cdots$$ also $$H_n(S^n)\cong H_0(S^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}\\H_i(S^n)=0\mbox{ for }i\neq 0,n$$ and finally if $A\to B\stackrel{f}{\to} C\to D$ is an exact sequence (or portion of one), then $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $A=0=D$.

Comment: Thanks, i already solve it (using this), thanks anyway for answer it :)